# Fql Limit Returns Less Results Than Expected

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get data from facebook by fql query.
One of the things I want to do is to get a litmited records each call. I am trying to do this by the 'LIMIT [start], [end]' command, it suppose to return to me the records between those numbers. Instead of getting [end]-[start] records which is the total number of records that are suppose to be returned. I get random number of records, I have checked and I can be sure that I am not trying to get more records that there is.

LIMIT example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT actor_id, message,description FROM  stream WHERE source_id =5878435678 Limit 2,10
```

This suppose to return 7 records (the count starts from 0) and I get only 3 records.
The funny thig is when I wrote instead of 10 50 I got 26 records.

Can someone help me to find a way how to get the exact ammount of records I asked for.
Tanks ahead!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This blog post by Facebook engineers explains this phenomenon.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Here's the part that addresses your question...

> You might notice that the number of results returned is not always
>   equal to the “limit” specified. This is expected behavior. Query
>   parameters are applied on our end before checking to see if the
>   results returned are visible to the viewer. Because of this, it is
>   possible that you might get fewer results than expected.

The below is the best part of the blog entry...

> This also means when you are manually constructing your own queries,
>   you should be aware that with some tables and connections if you are
>   specifying an “offset” parameter, the Nth result you are pointing to
>   may not get returned in your results (like the 3rd result in step 2 of
>   the image above). This can make paging difficult and confusing.

Lol, you're killing me Facebook!!!  Why not make it straight forward and consistent, rather than "difficult and confusing."?!?!?

Comment: +1, I read this post before but was unable to find it right away

Comment: @Why: Speed. Doing the "normal" fetch first and THEN filtering makes query caching a little bit easier (understatement). Otherwise they would either A have to fetch an unforefseeable amount of data or B have the database layer do specific queries for every possible combination of permissions. So, we just have to cope with that. :)

Comment: No, Most SQL systems can handle doing it correctly with incredible speed and will grab the correct amount of data requested. Why the FQL system cannot is merely a programmer/design decision that Facebook almost seems "proud" of based upon that blog entry.  I'd be ashamed if I was a dev on their FQL team of this blatant "short-cut" used.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exectly what I was looking for...
And yes they just can't let us have easy life.. I guess that's the curse of a programmer LOL

Comment: Guys you should pay attention that it always cuts from the end... so you can always count the number of posts you already have and start from there. In that way you shouldn't be concerned to miss some posts.

Comment: And I always thought programming was an exact «science»... Well, according to FB, this ain't the case :)

Comment: Actually it does NOT cut from the end. See the image at https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/paging2.png.  This is the one that has blue and red bars, and the red bars are removed from the result set.